# How to loop a set of code on Kotlin? (Android)

Tags: android, loops, kotlin

I have a button that changes the colour of a text. I want to change between the three colours. I've tried a while loop but the app simply would be blank. I've done some searching around but nothing I found worked.

Here is my MainActivity.kt code for the button:

```js
btnChangeColor.setOnClickListener {
            txtGavriel.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            txtGavriel.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 100f)


        btnChangeColor.setOnClickListener {
             txtGavriel.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)

        btnChangeColor.setOnClickListener {

            txtGavriel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        }

            }



        }
```

Comment: You mean you want to shuffle between the colors each click? You can achieve It with having an array of colors and a) randomly assigning a color each click b) saving a state and each click you can change the state and color accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you know where I can find somewhere to learn how to do this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
enum class Color { // I suppose that you have already defined this enum
    Blue, Red, Green
}

var state: Int = 0
val colors = Color.values()

txtGavriel.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 100f)

btnChangeColor.setOnClickListener {

  state = (state + 1) % colors.size
  txtGavriel.setTextColor(colors.get(state))

}
```